# JSON string to SQL

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a json string as below

```
DECLARE @jsonObjectDetails VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @jsonObjectDetails = '{
    "strObjectIDs": [
       {
          "Name":["Raj","Mohan","Shyam"],
          "Nametype": "First"
       },
       {
          "ID": ["RajL","MohanL","ShyamL"],
          "Nametype": "Last"
       }
    ],
    "Live": "Y"
}'
```

I need data output:

```
Name Nametype Live
Raj   First   y
Mohan First   y
Shyam First   y
Rajl  Last    y
Mohanl last   y
Shyaml last   y
```

Is there any function in SQL server to read the values of array of string in JSON and give output like above?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012; no. SQL Server 2016+ supports OPENJSON. I suggest upgrading to a supported version of SQL Server. Otherwise use a different to consume the data or you'll likely want a CLR function.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade from 2012, then maybe switch to XML over JSON? XML is supported in 2012 and can easily accomplish what you're looking to do.